# Приложение на Delphi для просмотра файлов формате PDF

Tags: pdf, delphi

Я написал приложение на Delphi 2009, отображающее содержимое PDF-файла. Для этого я импортировал Acrobat Access 3.0 Type Library. Инсталлировался пакет pdf.bpl в папке "`Document and Settings\All Users\Документы\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl\`". Появившийся компонент "TAcroPdf" был помещен в форму, он и принимает для отображения pdf-файлы.

Проблема такая: программа работает на компьютерах, где установлена Delphi, а на "чистых" - нет - на них после запуска выходит сообщение о не найденном классе и фатальная ошибка.

Я поместил файл pdf.bpl в каталог программы, потом добавил туда AcroPdf.dll - не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать

Answer (score 2):

Используйте компонент какой не будь для чтения **PDF** без использования **AcrobatReader**

Например **XpdfViewer Activex** или **Gnostice PDFtoolkit VCL ProPlus**

В общем [Гугль](google.com) и [Торри](torry.net) вам в помощь.

[Вот](programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?p=205276) еще статья по Вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Положить AcroPdf.dll например, в System32, и зарегистрировать

```
regsvr32 AcroPdf.dll
```

После этого все должно работать.
Ну или как уже сказали, отказаться от нее в пользу других компонентов.